# What is dual to relative homology?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $(X,A)$ be a pair of manifolds, where $A \subseteq X$. Then we can define the relative cohomology of the pair $H_{\bullet}(X,A)$ to be the homology of the chain complex $C_{\bullet}(X)/C_{\bullet}(A)$, where $C_{\bullet}(A), C_{\bullet}(X)$ are the singular chain complexes associated to $A$ and $X$ respectively.

We can also define relative de Rham cohomology of the pair $(X,A)$. I believe that for this you consider the double complex $\Omega^{\bullet}(X) \to \Omega^{\bullet}(A)$ (where we are pulling back forms by the inclusion map), take its total complex and then take its cohomology: $H^{\bullet}_{dR}(X,A)$.

From what I understand these two theories are not dual. So my question is: which cohomology theory is dual to the relative homology of the pair $(X,A)$.

Comment: Non-relative cohomology! See "Lefschetz duality".

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "dual." If you mean dual as in universal coefficients, the answer should still be relative cohomology, suitably defined. If you mean dual as Poincare duality, the answer comes from something called Lefschetz duality.

Comment: Oh cool, thanks. Know of any good references to learn about Lefschetz duality?

Comment: Any standard textbook will do...

Comment: Wait, why did everybody just assume that $A$ is the boundary of $X$?